# How to count number of characters and words in an HTML file or HTML string?

Tags: go

I have this string input from a HTML file:

```
<h1> Hello world </h1>
```

I want to count number of word and character of this file (not include HTML element)

For example:

```
Input 

<h1>Hello</h1>\n<h1>Hello</h1>

Output

Characters : 10
Word : 2
```

I believe there will be a step we parse this HTML content first. But I dont know which package support that.

Comment: To perform this kind of text parsing you often use Regex (in any language this would be the case). You should be able examples of a html removing regex online

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find them by regular expression.

```
    input := []byte("<h1>Hello</h1>\n<h1>Hello</h1>")

    tags, _ := regexp.Compile("(\\<\\/?[A-z0-9]+\\>)|(\\\\[A-z]{1})")
    // remove tags and backslash characters
    input = tags.ReplaceAll(input, []byte(" "))

    words, _ := regexp.Compile("[A-z0-9]+")
    // find all matched words and count them
    fmt.Println("total words: ", len(words.FindAll(input, -1)))

    chars, _ := regexp.Compile("[A-z0-9]{1}")
    // find all matched characters and count them
    fmt.Println("total characters: ", len(chars.FindAll(input, -1)))
```

output:

```
total words:  2
total characters:  10
```